# CSRF token using Craft as an API

Tags: csrf, post

Our Craft site needs to exchange data with our customer in-house APP. And at some point it needs for the APP to POST us updates.
We set some sort of API with a Api and Secret Key to exchange between platform. Everything works fine on DEV as we turned off the `enableCsrfProtection`. But sure enough won't work and obviously we need to keep it on for all the rest of the pages for security reason.

So my question is : How can the APP post us data with this security ON ? I mean it's not like we put a form with the value or anything like this. I'm puzzled. Sure enough I research and saw this page: https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/enabling-csrf-protection#updating-your-javascript but I don't see the solution it this... Maybe it's just me ! :D

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Another way of asking this (if I understand correctly) might be "How can I POST to a CSRF-protected action without a session?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few answers about controlling CSRF protection on a [per-endpoint basis](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/4553/whats-the-best-way-to-skip-csrf-for-plugin-controllers?rq=1), or for requests where a token needs to be [created on-the-fly](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/28735/csrf-in-headless-applications), but I think your question is unique.

It sounds like your client's internal application will be issuing a “stateless” request (i.e. without a session), sort of like a webhook. I'd also be willing to be that they can't or won't provide support for a custom handler capable of emulating a session—something that would require at least two discrete requests; one to start the session and get a token, and a second to submit it and the payload.

If you have a custom Controller receiving the data, you can tell it to ignore CSRF, without disabling it for the entire app…

```php
class AppHookController extends Controller
{
    public $enableCsrfValidation = false;

    // ...

    public function actionReceiveData()
    {
        // Your processing logic!
    }
}
```

…or even for a single action…

```php
class AppHookController extends Controller
{
    // ...

    public function beforeAction($action): bool
    {
        // Disable protection for only one action:
        if ($action->id === 'receive-data') {
            $this->enableCsrfProtection = false;
        }

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function actionReceiveData()
    {
        // Your processing logic!
    }
}
```

Either of these could be combined with a kind of "shared secret" between your site and the internal application that can be checked during the request.

If you are piggybacking on a built-in Craft controller, you can be notified when it is about to process a request:

```php
Event::on(
    EntriesController::class,
    EntriesController::EVENT_BEFORE_ACTION,
    function (ActionEvent $e) {
        $action = $e->action;
        $controller = $action->controller;

        if ($e->action->id === 'receive-data') {
            $controller->enableCsrfProtection = false;
        }
    });
```

☠️ I would strongly advise *not* deploying this solution, as misconfiguration can *significantly* impact the security of your application!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly it !

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve it using the answer August posted and created a tutorial that I hope helps others create APIs with Craft.

https://delasign.com/blog/craft-cms-api/